# Owin Start Url at end of existing domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

Im trying to start my Owin Self hosted in the end of my current domain.

For Example I have a MVC Site , hosted on IIS that runs in **[www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)** address

and now im trying to Load Self Hosted OWIN server in end of that address like this

**[www.abc.com/sampleOwinServer](http://www.abc.com/sampleOwinServer)** .

The Owin project is a Class Library that referenced in another MVC Project and Im

Instantiating it with reflection (starting the owin server inside it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use IIS in reverse proxy mode. I mean just host your selfhosted application in specific port in localhost, and then use this article to configure IIS as reverse proxy and rewrite url to your self hosted application.

https://docs.microfocus.com/OMi/10.62/Content/OMi/AdminGuide/Hardening/RevProxy_IIS.htm#Configure

Note: Using IIS is not the best approach. I highly recommend you to use modern reverse proxies like nginx or envoy.